# How to update pickled objects when adding an attribute to a Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I defined a Python3 class and then used pickle to serialize and save an instance to file. Later I added another instance attribute to my class, but I realized that if I load my instance and try to reference that attribute I will get an "Object has no attribute" error since the instance was constructed without it. What are the best options for adding the new attribute to my pickled object(s) and configuring it?

In code, I defined a class like

```
# First definition
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, params):
    # define and initialize attributes
  def print_number(self):
    print(2)
```

I create and serialize an instance using pickle, and save it to file

```
import pickle

inst = Foo(params)
with open("filename", 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(inst, f)
```

Then I want my class to behave a bit differently, so I update its definition:

```
# Updated definition
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, params):
    # define and initialize attributes
    self.bar = "baz"                    # bar is a new attribute
  def print_number(self):
    print(3)                            # prints 3 instead of 2
```

Then I load my instance and try to call some methods

```
import pickle

with open("filename", 'rb') as f:
  inst = pickle.load(f)

inst.print_number()
print(inst.bar)
```

Since pickle doesn't save method definitions, the instance method's behaviour is updated so `inst.print_number()` prints `3` instead of `2`. However the reference `inst.bar` results in an "Object has no attribute" error because `inst` was initialized before `Foo` had that attribute in its definition.

**Update**

This was a bit of a noob question on my part, I didn't realize that Python lets you just do something like `inst.bar = "baz"` and set things dynamically (I'm coming from a Java background where everything has to be fixed from the start). I am still interested in hearing about ways to do this properly and/or Pythonicaly and/or pickle-specificly, especially when multiple class updates can be expected.

Comment: Why don't you just save the `instance.__dict__` and class it refers to, then recreate it when loading? (e.g. `pickle.dump(inst.__dict__, f)` to save, `inst = Foo.__new__(); inst.__dict__.update(pickle.load(f))` to load). That way you only save/update the inner state without actually pickling the instance. That being said, it's generally not a good idea to change definitions after saving states - if you expect that to happen on a regular basis maybe you should rethink your design and handle save/load states on your own instead of relying on the inefficient pickle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) to add new methods/attributes to an existing class:

```
# First definition
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
    def print_number(self):
        print(2)

import pickle

inst = Foo('params')
with open("filename", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(inst, f)

del inst

# Updated definition
class Foo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__(params)
        self.bar = "baz"                    # bar is a new attribute
    def print_number(self):
        print(3)


with open("filename", 'rb') as f:
    inst = Foo(pickle.load(f))

inst.print_number()
print(inst.bar)

# Outputs:
# 3
# baz
```

Or it probably makes more sense in practice to do something like this:

```
with open("filename", 'rb') as f:
    inst = pickle.load(f)

# Updated definition
class Foo(inst.__class__):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__(params)
        self.bar = "baz"                    # bar is a new attribute
    def print_number(self):
        print(3)



inst = Foo(inst)
inst.print_number()
print(inst.bar)
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Could something like this be suitable for making multiple updates?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why not

Answer (score 0):

The general way I would go about this is by implementing `__setstate__`. I've pasted some code below that you can play with to get a feel for how it might work. You can also define a method that both `__setstate__` and `__init__` call with a `dict` (either the keyword arguments to `__init__` or the state given to `__setstate__`)  that will ensure the expected attributes are all set regardless of how the object is created. You might also consider implementing `__new__` for your class since that gets called even for unpickling.

mod.py:

```py
VERSION = 1

if VERSION == 1:
    # Version 1
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            # Note: either the instance's dict has to have something set or __getstate__
            # has to be overridden to return a `value` for which `bool(value) == True`
            #
            # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__
            self.some_attr = 2
elif VERSION == 2:
    # Version 2
    class A:
        def __new__(cls):
            inst = super().__new__(cls)
            inst.other_new_attr = 6
            return inst

        def __init__(self):
            self.some_attr = 2
            self.new_attr = 5

        def __setstate__(self, state):
            print('setting state', state)
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            if not hasattr(self, 'new_attr'):
                print('adding new_attr')
                # you can do whatever you want to calculate new_attr here
                self.new_attr = 5
```

run.py:

```py
import sys
from mod import A
from pickle import dump, load


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'dump':
        with open('a.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            dump(A(), f)
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'load':
        # call this after adding the attribute
        with open('a.pickle', 'rb') as f:
            a = load(f)
        print(a.new_attr)
        print(a.other_new_attr)
```